# Struggling to convert my int solution to type String when displaying it in my richtextbox

Tags: c#

```
    private void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int solution;

       String value = "";
        //double pound = 20.09;
        double rand = (double.Parse(value));
        if (pound.Checked == true)
        {
            solution = (int)(rand * 20.09);
           rich.Text = Convert.toString(solution);
        }

        else if (dollar.Checked == true)
        {
            solution = (int)(rand * 16.92);
          rich.Text = Convert.toString(solution);
        }

        else if (euro.Checked == true)
        {
            solution = (int)(rand * 17.06);          
            rich.Text = Convert.toString(solution); 
            // The error I receive is that no overload methods for "Tostring" takes 1 argument 

        }
    }
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString` note capitalization - `To`, not `to`

Comment: Use solution.ToString() instead

Comment: @Romka: usually `solution.ToString()` is more *flexible* (we can provide format string, say `f2`) and that's why preferable in many cases; however, here `Convert.ToString(solution)` and `solution.ToString()` are interchangeable

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes, but it can help him to find the problem, since the error is at compile-time with the Convert.ToString method. As x.ToString() is inherited from Object, it 'cannot' bug in its case, and he will have something in its richtextBox, helping to find the issue

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with you code. The very first one is syntactical

```
Convert.toString(solution); // <- doesn't compile
```

When compiler *complains* like

> ...no overload methods for "toString" takes 1 argument...

it means that the method with such signature *doesn't exist*. The cause is usually a *typo*, wrong order or types of arguments, extra arguments etc.

Here you have a *typo*. The right syntax is `Convert.ToString(solution);`, note the **capitalization**, `To`, not `to`.

Another problem is at the very beginning:

```
String value = "";
//double pound = 20.09;
// the next line will throw exception, "" can't be parsed into a double
double rand = (double.Parse(value)); // <- runtime problem here
```

you should read value from some `TextBox`, `RichEdit` etc., say

```
String value = myTextBox.Text;
```

Finally, don't repeat yourself: you don't have to put that many `Convert.ToString`; if

You extract business logic as property / method (`CurrencyRate`) you can have

```
private double CurrencyRate {
  get => pound.Checked  ? 20.09 
       : dollar.Checked ? 16.92
       : euro.Checked   ? 17.06
       : double.NaN;  
}

private void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (double.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out var rand) && !double.IsNaN(CurrencyRate)) 
    rich.Text = $"{(int)(rand * CurrencyRate)}";
}
```

Here I've preserved your *truncation* to int - `$"{(int)(rand * CurrencyRate)}"`, but when working with currencies you can well want to represent the result with 2 digits after the decimal point: `$"{rand * CurrencyRate:f2}"`